# SlidingPaneLayout - faded views have strange background

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, slidingpanelayout

I have problem with SlidingPaneLayout.
When I open menu (made with spl), all views (textviews, imageviews, etc.) look like these textviews on screenshot (they have strange color around text, 25th is ok - this one is green when visible):

[image]

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You just have to add the following line to your code:

```
mSlidingPane.setSliderFadeColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

For more info see the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html#setSliderFadeColor%28int%29)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. I want to achieve the effect of fade. This solution totally disables it.

Comment: Well you asked what color should be set to transparent... Seems like your questions isn't clear enough.

Comment: But what color of textview / imageview, not slidingpanelayout.
I've removed this additional question.

Comment: So you wan't the right pane (contentpane) to be dimmed with, let's say, a pink color?

Comment: No. I want the views on content pane to be properly dimmed.
TextViews have some strange background around text. ImageViews have some strange background around images, etc.

Comment: This works for me, that would disable it totally. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to 'reVerse' answer:

1. set your custom color:

   mSlidingPane.setSliderFadeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor));
2. Important: Make sure that your slided layout has a background color (any color is okey).

This works:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/SlidingPanel"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:id = "@+id/drawerContainer"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_light">
    <!--- your content here -->
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

To mimic the general grey background you can use:

```
<color name="grey_light">#fffafafa</color>
```